# mvvm add two textbox insert value on other textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello everyone I have a problem, I have to add two textbox float, and put the result in another textbox without using codebehind the two textboxes are bindate to their property. Thank you all in advance for the help

Comment: Where is the code that you have implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Your view model will consist of three properties. First two properties will be two-way binded to input textboxes. Third property will return the sum of first and second property and it's binded to third textbox which is used only for output.

When you edit first or second property they also will notify `third property changed`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private string _firstText;
    public string FirstText 
    {
        get  {return _firstText; } 
        set { _firstText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FirstAndSecondText"); }
    }

    private string _secondText;
    public string SecondTExt
    {
        get  {return _secondText; } 
        set { _secondText= value; RaisePropertyChanged("FirstAndSecondText"); }
    }

    public string FirstAndSecondText {get {return FirstText + SecondText; }}
}
```

In xaml:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding FirstText, Mode=TwoWay} />
<TextBox Text={Binding SecondText, Mode=TwoWay} />
<TextBox Text={Binding FirstAndSecondText} />
```

`RaisePropertyChanged` is not built in method. You must implement INotificationProperty interface or inherit a special helper classes like `ViewModelBase` in MVVM Light toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

here how to do it :
First in your view model define three float properties :

```
 private float _floatOne;
    public float FloatOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _floatOne;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_floatOne == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _floatOne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Result = _floatOne + _floatTwo;
        }
    }
    private float _floatTwo;
    public float FloatTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return _floatTwo;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_floatTwo == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _floatTwo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Result = _floatOne + _floatTwo;
        }
    }



    private float _result;
    public float Result
    {
        get
        {
            return _result;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_result == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _result = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

the `OnPropertyChanged` method will notify the UI for any changes, and it is the result of implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface,
Secondly in your Xaml bind those properties to your textBoxes like so :

```
<StackPanel>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding FloatOne,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding FloatTwo,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Result,Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help me I have make:

```
public double Ricambi
{
    get { return _Ricambi; }
    set
    {
        _Ricambi = value; _Totale = _Ricambi + _Manifattura; RaisePropertyChanged("Ricambi"); RaisePropertyChanged("Totale");
    }
}

public double Manifattura
{
    get { return _Manifattura;  }
    set { _Manifattura = value;_Totale = _Ricambi + _Manifattura; RaisePropertyChanged("Manifattura"); RaisePropertyChanged("Totale"); }
}

public double Totale
{   
    get { return _Totale; }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer @JesseJames solution because you don't repeat your definition of what `_Totale` is. With the solution you've chosen you now have two places in the code to maintain that formula. Yes it is a simple formula, but repeating it is not a good idea. JesseJames solution defined that in only one place, so if it needed to change you had no danger of missing a definition scattered around the code. BTW, if these answers helped you then Upvote them and choose one as the selected answer.